# Bitrix24 (облако) встраивание приложения в меню контакта

Tags: javascript, битрикс

Добрый день.

Изучаю приложения Bitrix. Есть у них т.н. "*приложения первого типа*" - содержат обычные файлы html и js, общаются с API Битрикса с помощью специальной JS библиотеки. Проблем с добавлением самого приложения нет, проблем с обращением к данным Битрикса тоже нет - я могу спокойно получить список контактов или клиентов и т.д.

Вопрос в следующем - как встроить пункт вызова этого приложения в меню, к примеру, контакта?

Пошерстил руководство, нашел метод REST API - placement.bind. Нашел уроки, но все они касаются внешних приложений - с использованием access_token авторизации через OAth... Также смущает обязательность использования параметра HANDLER - в мануале это URL обработчика (по сути внешнего приложения), а мой обработчик тут же вот, во фрейме самого Битрикс.

В описании самого битрикс сказано, что все токены разрешений передаются приложению первого типа в момент вызова. Подозреваю, что требуется использовать файл install.html с вызовом методов Битрикса для встраивания приложения, но поиск в сети не даёт примеров хотя бы в общем виде.

Запрос в поддержку Битрикс отправлял, ответа от них пока что не поступало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тоже сегодня столкнулся с этим. Думал уже что для первого типа нельзя так сделать, но в итоге получилось!
Шаги следующие.
Делаем install.html и в нем вызываем (по кнопке или в ините) тот самый метод placement.bind.

Вот типа так:
`BX24.callMethod('placement.bind', { PLACEMENT: 'CRM_LEAD_LIST_MENU', HANDLER: "URL", TITLE: 'Приложение', DESCRIPTION: 'Тестовое приложение' });`

Главная проблема тут в свойстве URL. Его придется брать из формы редактирования приложения. Т.е. сначала надо загрузить архив, потом не открывая приложения, зайти в редактирование, скопировать оттуда ссылку и прописать в наш код, и тут же залить архив с исправлением.
Ну а дальше открываем приложение, метод срабатывает и ссылка встраивается туда куда указали (в моем примере в контекстное меню лида).
Метод костыльный но работает.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, примерно так я и думал. Правда что-то у меня не вышло - запихнул вызов метода в BX24.init файла install.html, сделал как вы написали, но результата нет... ни ошибки, ни пункта в меню. сейчас хочу попробовать BX24.init на BX24.install заменить.

Comment: Что-то я видимо делаю не так... `BX24.install(function()
{
 BX24.callMethod('placement.bind', {PLACEMENT: 'CRM_CONTACT_LIST_MENU', HANDLER: 'https://apps-b1011945.bitrix24-cdn.com/b1011945/app_local/7c0aa73da3f6445258f8437ccd123aa9/index.html', TITLE: 'Приложение', DESCRIPTION: 'Тестовое приложение'}, function(result){console.log(result);BX24.installFinish();});
});` не хочет работать...

Comment: Алексей учитывайте что url меняется каждый раз когда вы открываете приложение для редактирования.  вызывал метод с клика по кнопке но и из BX24.init(function () {})  тоже должно быть.
Еще - дебажте метод placement.bind. Он возвращает ответ. 
```BX24.callMethod('placement.bind', {ваши параметры}, (result) => { console.log(result)});```